# Integration dilemma

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to compute the value of $$\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{4ie^{it}}{4e^{it}-3}\,\mathrm{d}t$$
Using the Maple software, the answer is $2\pi i$. However, when I worked it out myself, I got $0$ instead.

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{4ie^{it}}{4e^{it}-3}\,\mathrm{d}t&=\ln\left|4e^{it}-3\right|\Bigg|_0^{2\pi}\\
&=0
\end{align}

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you're integrating across a branch cut.  Your answer is right, but you need to use the complex logarithm, which is multi-valued.  If you plot the curve $4e^{it}-3$ in the complex plane, you'll see that it goes around the origin.  Therefore, you'll need to increase the argument as you travel around the origin.

Comment: Another side of this.  The formula $\int(1/x)\;dx = \log |x|+C$ is only for real integrals, not complex integrals.  The complex version is $\int (1/z)\;dz = \log z + C$, no absolute value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integral is the contour integral

$$\int_{|z| = 4} \frac{dz}{z - 3}$$

Since $3$ lies inside the circle $|z| = 4$, by the Cauchy integral formula, the value of the integral is $2\pi i$.

Even for using logs, your calculation is incorrect because you only captured the real part of the antiderivative of $4ie^{it}/(4e^{it} - 3)$, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithmic function defined for complex numbers has branch cuts depending on where you want the branch cuts to be. They are not continuous; the above integral expression should be computed by using the limit instead of plugging in the values. There's your mistake.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please try to write using proper English instead of textspeak. Others may take you less seriously if you write for example "u" instead of "you" as you did.